# TextToSpeech onInit() not fired

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I cannot get TextToSpeech running. New TextToSpeech instance is created, but onInit() gets never called.
i call the setup() method in my Fragments onCreate()

```
public class SpeakerManager {

    private static TextToSpeech speaker;

    public static void setup() {
        if(speaker == null) {
            speaker = new TextToSpeech(MyApp.getAppContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                        speaker.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Code seems fine to me.
I also get these Logs, after calling setup():

```
I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

When i use speak() method i get this Log:

```
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: TTS engine connection not fully set up
```

I tested with multiple devices and emulators.
It's a big app. Could there be some configs in code or manifest which blocks TextToSpeech? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the text to speech engine you are using requires an Internet connection, and you don't have that? Or maybe it requires the internet permission to be able to use the internet connection? Or are these engines installed as separate applications with their own permissions?

Comment: I don't know i didnt configure any text to speech engine. But i have Internet connection and permissions for sure